# Accessing masterpage property from a usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I access a property defined on my masterpage from codebehind in a usercontrol?

Answer (score 17):

```
var master = (this.Page.Master as SiteMaster);
if (master != null)
{
    var myProperty = master.MyProperty;
}
```

Comment: There is no [`MasterType` directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228274.aspx) for a user control, I guess?

Comment: The type or namespace SiterMaster could not be found

Comment: @Johan, yes, this is the actual type of your master page. For example if you have a Site.Master then use SiteMaster,  if you have FooBar.Matser then use FooBarMaster, ...

Comment: Base.Master, if i use as Base, it works when im on the masterpage, but not in the usercontrol.

Answer (score 6):

[Page.Master](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.master.aspx) exposes the underlying master page, if any.

Answer (score 3):

As much as I understood:

1. there is a Master Page (MasterPage.master)
2. a web page (Default.aspx) which is using MasterPage.
3. the webpage has a user control.
4. Now you want to access a property of a MasterPage from this user control.

Lets say in the MasterPage there is a property called name like

```
public string Name{ get{return "ABC";} }
```

Now you want to access this property from the UserControl.

For this purpose you'll first have to register the master page in the user control like this.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mp" TagName="MyMP" Src="~/MasterPage.master" %>
```

Now you'll first have to get the reference of the page this user control is residing in and then get the Master Page of that page. The code will be  like this.

```
System.Web.UI.Page page = (System.Web.UI.Page)this.Page;
MasterPage1 mp1 = (MasterPage1)page.Master;

lbl1.Text= mp1.Name;
```

Comment: The master page which needs to be visible on the user controls

Comment: Register change nothing in my case, the MasterPage is still not defined in my userControl code-behind

Comment: This worked for me without actually having to register the master

Answer (score 2):

```
this.NamingContainer.Page.Master.Property;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the MasterPage is like this,

```
public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //
    }

    // the property which I would like to access from user control  
    public String MyName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Nazmul";
        }
    }  
}
```

Then from the user control, you can access "MyName" by this way,

```
MasterPage m = Page.Master as MasterPage;
Type t = m.GetType();

System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi = t.GetProperty("MyName");

Response.Write( pi.GetValue(m,null)); //return "Nazmul"
```

Answer (score -1):

In Case of your Master Page is fixed than You can find control and property like this:

```
    MasterPageName mp =(MasterPageName) Page.Master;
   //find a control
    Response.Write((mp.FindControl("txtmaster") as TextBox).Text);
   //find a property
   Response.Write(mp.MyProperty.Text);
```

//on MasterPageName.cs

```
 public TextBox MyProperty
 {
    get { return txtmaster; }
 }
```

//on MasterPageName.Master

`<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtmaster"></asp:TextBox>`